# How to compile output of a compiler phase?

Tags: scala, scalac, scala-compiler

Using `-Xprint` flag in `scalac` we get output of different [compiler phases](https://typelevel.org/scala/docs/phases.html), for example given the following `Foo.scala`

```
object Foo {
  val x = 42
}
```

then `scalac -Xprint:jvm Foo.scala` outputs

```
package <empty> {
  object Foo extends Object {
    <static> private[this] val x: Int = _;
    <stable> <accessor> def x(): Int = Foo.this.x;
    def <init>(): Foo.type = {
      Foo.super.<init>();
      Foo.this.x = 42;
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

How to compile the phase itself, that is, say we have source file `jvmphase.scala` like so

```
package <empty> { ...
```

containing the phase source code instead of the original vanilla Scala source code, then how to achieve something similar to `scalac jvmphase.scala`?

Comment: I guess you can redirect the output to a file and then compile that file?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I tried that, it does not seem to work. For example, it does not recognise `<empty>` giving `identifier expected but $XMLSTART$< found`.

Comment: @MarioGalic Why do you need this?

Comment: @DmytroMitin Just for learning and experimentation purposes I would like to make changes to phase code and see what happens. Perhaps learning how to write the "lowest-level" de-sugared Scala code would make me understand "sugared" Scala better.

Comment: @MarioGalic If you want to make changes between phases maybe you should create compiler plugin.

Comment: @MarioGalic "compiling output of a compiler phase" sounds strange. Literally compiler compiles source file. Output of a compiler phase is not a source any more. For example `jvm` phase is after `erasure` phase. And it's not clear what you expect to get while "compiling output of a compiler phase" besides result of compilation of the original source.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Ah, it seems I miss understood what phase output is. I assumed because it looks a bit like source code it is something I could write. Consider putting your comments in an answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"compiling output of a compiler phase" sounds strange. Literally compiler compiles source file. Output of a compiler phase is not a source any more (although `scalac -Xprint:...` tries to print it similarly). For example `jvm` phase is after `erasure` phase. And it's not clear what you expect to get while "compiling output of a compiler phase" besides result of compilation of the original source.

If you want to make changes between phases maybe you should create compiler plugin.

https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/plugins/index.html

https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/compiler-plugins.html